# Plato's Phaedo : Why does the soul stay separate from the body?

Tags: metaphysics, plato, death, souls

In Plato's Phaedo, Socrates established that death is the separation of soul and body. But he did not give any clue for this separation.  What are the factors that lead to this separation? Physical conditions of the body are an apparent cause of this separation. But sometimes a healthy person suddenly dies whatever the physical cause is and it is even earlier for ailing people. Another sub-question arises: Which one is the cause and which one is the effect? Is it death that causes separation of soul and body OR separation of soul and body that causes death?

Comment: There is no "theory of the afterlife" in Plato: thus, it is hard to answer. Death is a "physical" process thta affects body. When the body perishes, the **immortal** soul obviously departs.